# Azure blob storage "Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header."

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Following the [quickstart here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python)

I use `DefaultAzureCredential`
My code

```
import os
import uuid
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, ContainerClient, BlobClient

try:
    account_url = 'https://kindglacierblob.blob.core.windows.net'
    default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url, credential=default_credential)
    container_name = str(uuid.uuid4())
    container_client = blob_service_client.create_container(container_name)

except Exception as e:
    print(e) # See error details below
```

Server failed to authenticate the request.

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidAuthenticationInfo</Code>
<Message>
    Server failed to authenticate the request. 
    Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.
    RequestId:23153837-001e-0019-6585-855a4a000000
    Time:2023-05-13T10:28:57.2758247Z
</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>
    Issuer validation failed. Issuer did not match.
</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

When I print `e.response.request.url`:

```
'https://kindglacierblob.blob.core.windows.net/40803991-619c-4cc6-8931-cfdbae302438?restype=container'
```

When I print `e.response.request.headers`:

```
{   'Accept': 'application/xml',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '
                     'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ii1LSTNROW5OUjdiUm9meG1lWm9YcWJIWkdldyIsImtpZCI6Ii1LSTNROW5OUjdiUm9meG1lWm9YcWJIWkdldyJ9.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.qM56mzD09cB1oLW2sa-aZiPsgCCr7cnZ8mlYv5cTHK8pZLlEyXf5404EVrIas7N5tPhiBFL6qq_7znD-4NPFBFK0qWdGIi4BN66T1c5U81wJQl1VgDK4KoHxh2LmUtfYiDHne8LKQ7dLO_WSd-LWb_eTVSEg_0rEOxWjRpcgwRSrvYw98sWdIoIp0doPAmqXeI_IQcDdvWEu6rSMsTd74CjMRaTwFAFpclDazzCWz_kFOMRfaro4s03Ki-7CYRZj-JI49mKvCThXrphLBfOU2B_VrEg4HJNwOb55nFc2WS5l9r0WBh1AlhQa9i7NvmP-OoEZi8gox4HMJeKz6h-pDg',
    'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.16.0 Python/3.11.2 '
                  '(Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0)',
    'x-ms-client-request-id': 'f69db4e3-f178-11ed-b2a7-f89e94c65957',
    'x-ms-date': 'Sat, 13 May 2023 10:28:55 GMT',
    'x-ms-version': '2022-11-02'}
```

When I print `e.response.headers` (notice the value of the `www-authenticate` header):

```
{   'Content-Length': '402',
    'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
    'Date': 'Sat, 13 May 2023 10:28:56 GMT',
    'Server': 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0',
    'WWW-Authenticate': 'Bearer '
                        'authorization_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/0091f901-8eb9-49ad-a413-3bd58cb1aff0/oauth2/authorize '
                        'resource_id=https://storage.azure.com',
    'x-ms-error-code': 'InvalidAuthenticationInfo',
    'x-ms-request-id': '23153837-001e-0019-6585-855a4a000000'}
```

Similar questions/ what I tried:

- [AzureStorage Blob Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492790/azurestorage-blob-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request-make-sure-the-value)

  - I synced my PC's time as suggested in the accepted answer, I think it's accurately showing GMT
- [How to fix Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75981712/1175496)

  - but I'm not using a SAS / Account Key in my URL
- [Azure Blob Storage - Server failed to authenticate the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46936817/azure-blob-storage-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request)

  - but I don't have the same error message "Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."

I assigned myself "Storage Blob Data Contributor" for the kindglacierblob Blob, [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python?tabs=managed-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli#assign-roles-to-your-azure-ad-user-account) (screenshot below)

[image: screenshot of Azure Portal IAM showing I assigned myself "Storage Blob Data Contributor" for the kindglacierblob Blob]

Running with Visual Studio Code
[I logged in using the VS Code "Azure Account Extension"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-python#authenticate-via-visual-studio-code), as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot showing logged in using the VS Code "Azure Account Extension"]

I tried to login by opening Azure CLI in a new VS Code Terminal, but I get an unrelated error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'vscode'
Require stack:
- c:\Users\nateanderson\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.azure-account-0.11.4\dist\cloudConsoleLauncher.js
```

With the popup:

```
The terminal process "node.exe '-e', 'require('c:\\Users\\nateanderson\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-vscode.azure-account-0.11.4\\dist\\cloudConsoleLauncher').main()'" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @TomW,  I used `pprint`  to output my headers, including `WWW-authenticate`, which contains `authorization_uri`, but I don't see two GUIDs in the `authorization_uri`, only one? (36 characters including hyphens, right?).  `authorization_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/0091f901-8eb9-49ad-a413-3bd58cb1aff0/oauth2/authorize`

Comment: Oops - I'm seeing things - possibly something to do with fat-fingering the scrollbar on my mobile. When I re-read the question on a good-sized screen, nothing untoward here. Comment retracted.

Comment: I appreciate your eyes on the question anyway, I feel like I must be making some simple mistake here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I decode your JWT in https://jwt.io I get:

[image: screenshot of the issuer claim of the decoded JWT]

and looking at the idp claim:

[image: screenshot of the idp claim of the decoded JWT]

This to me looks as though the `DefaultAzureCredential` has picked up an active login to your Microsoft account that has been issued by the Windows Live authorization server, rather than the Azure Active Directory authorization server, and that would seem to be different enough that this isn't good enough for Azure - even though they clearly share the same identity database since you can sign into both with your Microsoft account. I'm not familiar with the Python SDK so can't suggest what options might be available to fine-tune this.

**EDIT**

You can decode the JWT used in the Authorization header to see username is being used to log in (screenshot below)

As explained in the comments, it was not the username you expected.

[image: take the Authorization JWT token and decode to find out which user is being used to authorize your access to Blob Storage]

With the Python `azure-login` library, you can specify the username you really want to use with the `shared_cache_username` keyword argument, as shown here:
[image]

Analogous to the .NET [`DefaultAzureCredentialOptions.SharedTokenCacheUsername`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredentialoptions.sharedtokencacheusername?view=azure-dotnet#azure-identity-defaultazurecredentialoptions-sharedtokencacheusername) property, the Python `shared_cache_username` argument [is described as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-python):

> Preferred username for  [`azure.identity.SharedTokenCacheCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.sharedtokencachecredential?view=azure-python).
> Defaults to the value of environment variable `AZURE_USERNAME`, if any.

Therefore another option (instead of setting shared cache username in your **code**) is to SET the `AZURE_USERNAME` **environment variable** (which can be done [using Git Bash (shown below)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34169743/1175496), or [Windows cmd.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1)):

```
export AZURE_USERNAME=<your_username>
```

Or if you're using VSCode to develop and debug, you could add the environment variable into your [launch.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes), you could try adding this:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "env": {
        "AZURE_USERNAME": "{your username here}"
      },
    ...
```

[image: screenshot of launch.json file using the "env" to set environment variable "AZURE_USERNAME"]

Comment: I think you're onto something, when I decode the JWT payload (found in `e.response.request.headers['Authorization']`), I see  "email": "theredpea@gmail.com" -- that's my **personal email** (my personal email *does have* a Microsoft account, but does not have access to this blob storage; I gave access to my **work account/work email**)... Once we find the details to fix this (or at least verify it) I'll mark your answer correct. I'll try to a) login with my work account.... b) giving my personal email access to this blob storage... (not ideal)

Comment: ['`SharedTokenCacheUsername`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredentialoptions.sharedtokencacheusername#azure-identity-defaultazurecredentialoptions-sharedtokencacheusername) on `DefaultAzureCredentialOptions` looks like what you want, assuming the python SDK supports it.

Comment: Thanks, @TomW! You left me to the issue and suggested the right fix. I edited your answer to include the details of the fix -- please undo my edits if you don't like them.